# How can I configure Solr (like solrconfig.xml) so that the "~"/fuzzy query is implied without be having to add it to the end of all queries?

Tags: solr, solr5

I am currently using Apache Solr 5.5.1 and I would like to generate fuzzy results without having to add the "~" at the end of the query.  As an example if I run a query against "Fellowships" it does not find any records that contain "fellowship" without the ending "s" but if I run the query against "Fellowships~" it does find these "fellowship" records.  How can I configure Solr (like solrconfig.xml) so that the "~"/fuzzy query is implied without be having to add it to the end of all queries?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using a stemmer to actually stem terms to their common format, instead of using fuzzy search to achieve the same.

There is no way to make all terms behave fuzzy, as it's part of the query syntax and not an argument by itself. If you really want to apply it as a fuzzy query, append the `~x` in your middleware.