# How to configure sorted fuzzy search without fuzzy operand in the query in SOLR

Tags: solr, server-side, fuzzy, operands

The following query does a sorted fuzzy search in SOLR 9.3

```
{!type=complexphrase inOrder=true}Appfel~1
```

where

| Parameter | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `{! }` | Local query parameter referred in SOLR documentation as LocalParams |
| `type=complexphrase` | Use ComplexPhraseQParser |
| `inOrder=true` | How the query should be handled |
| `~1` | Use fuzzy search of edit distance 1 |

and delivers desired results - german words similar to Apfel. So far so good.

What I would like to achieve is to move the configuration from query string into the SOLR backend (for instance into solrconfig.xml), so that the client does not need to know anything about SOLR specific logic. My goal is to let the client search with

`q=Appfel`

which SOLR server translates into:

`{!type=complexphrase inOrder=true}Appfel~1`

A solution for the first part with ComplexPhraseQParser I could find:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">complexphrase</str>
    <str name="df">myField</str>
    <str name="inOrder">true</str>
    ...
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

but for the FUZZY operand I cannot find a way to set it as a default for all queries. I've tried

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    ...
    <str name="q.op">FUZZY</str>
    ...
</requestHandler>
```

without any success. I've found the [QParserPlugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrPlugins#SolrPlugins-QParserPlugin) - but before I will code a new subclass, I would like to ask in this forum first.

How to configure "~1" for all queries by default in the SOLR server configuration?

The same [question for SOLR 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421262/how-can-i-configure-solr-like-solrconfig-xml-so-that-the-fuzzy-query-is-im) - without a solution.

Comment: Just a small note - `inOrder=true` does not mean that the results are sorted. It means that the tokens given should be in order - i.e. that if you're searching `name:"Fo* Bar"`, `Foo` needs to appear before `Bar`. It's how the query should be handled, not how the results should be sorted.

Comment: Thanks, you are right - I missed that point